# Adding Microsoft Band SDK to Visual Studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio, sdk

I've downloaded the *Microsoft Band SDK* from [here.](http://developer.microsoftband.com/)
And I've *Microsoft Visual Studio Express 2013 for Windows with Update 4* installed on my PC. I wanted to know how to start working on the SDK because when I open the solution (*Microsoft Band SDK Samples.sln*) file in *Visual Studio* I get a dialog stating that **it doesn't support the SDK**  and on the *Solution Explorer* the *Demo*, *Personalisation*, *Sensors* and *Tiles* tabs have **(incompatible)** after them. I opened the *readme* file> under *INSTALLATION INSTRUCTIONS* I've followed all of them (even after adding a reference to the *Microsoft Band SDK NuGet package* to the application) it still shows **incompatible**!

How to solve this?

Thanks,
Kvaibhav01.

Comment: Were you able to get it to work?

Comment: No @ Iris Classon....it didn't even opened it! Shows incompatible!

Comment: did you find any solution? what kind of projects do you create?

Comment: Hey @MonaJalal, I'm beginner in Band SDK development so now experience.